# How do I set my Android app package name based on two different flavor dimensions?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm building my Android app with the Gradle plugin.  I'm using the flavors feature to create four different variants.  At the moment, it's a single dimension with four values, but it would be more logical to set it up as two dimensions with two values each.  I've got that building, but this is where I run into trouble.

I need each of the four variants to have a different package name.  The first three are easy since I have a default and each dimension can override the package, but I need to set a package name for when both non-default dimensions are in play.

```
flavorDimensions "foo", "bar"
productFlavors {
    boring.flavorDimension "foo"
    charm {
        flavorDimension "foo"
        packageName "com.example.charm"
    }
    strange {
        flavorDimension "bar"
        packageName "com.example.strange"
    }
    // This is the idea of what I want, but it doesn't work because there
    // must be only a single dimension specified here.
    charmStrange {
        flavorDimension "foo", "bar"
        packageName "com.example.charminglystrange"
    }
}
```

I tried setting it after declaration by looking up the composed flavor variant, but I didn't have much luck.  I'm not very familiar with Gradle, so I'm sure there's trickery I haven't employed.  Alternately, maybe I could specify the package name in `src/charmStrange/AndroidManifest.xml` and let the merge sort it out?  That seems like it could cause problems in the future.

Comment: Don't set the name in the manifest, it will get overwritten during the Gradle build process

Comment: How are the dimensions different? Why can't you use a single package name? How much space will you really be saving using that strategy?

Comment: @StephanBranczyk They're different in terms of having slightly different business rules, so a single APK is out of the question.  Fortunately for me, one of those axes has since disappeared so the question is moot.  Although I'd still be curious about an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar question this answer isn't tested in my case I was appending the product flavor to the app id set by the other dimension, using your example it would append .strange to package com.example.charm

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def flavorString = variant.getVariantData().getVariantConfiguration().getFlavorName()
    def mergedFlavour = variant.getVariantData().getVariantConfiguration().getMergedFlavor();
    def appId = variant.getVariantData().getVariantConfiguration().getApplicationId();

    if(flavorString.contains("Strange")) {
        mergedFlavour.setApplicationId(appId + ".strange")
    }


}
```

but in your case you want a full package name so something like

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def flavorString = variant.getVariantData().getVariantConfiguration().getFlavorName()
    def mergedFlavour = variant.getVariantData().getVariantConfiguration().getMergedFlavor();
    def appId = variant.getVariantData().getVariantConfiguration().getApplicationId();

    if(flavorString.contains("charmStrange")) {
        mergedFlavour.setApplicationId("com.example.charminglystrange)
    }


}
```

charmStrange might need to be CharmStrange, try playing with it

Answer (score 3):

You can now set applicationIdSuffix for productFlavors:

```
android {  
     productFlavors {  
          free {   
               applicationIdSuffix = ".free"  
          }  
          prod {

          } 
     }  
}
```

Source:
http://android-developers.blogspot.ie/2015/12/leveraging-product-flavors-in-android.html

Comment: If I weren't stuck with some legacy names that make this insufficient for my needs, I'd be all aboard.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to set the applicationId, not the packageName:

```
    productFlavors {
        boring.flavorDimension "foo"
        charm {
            flavorDimension "foo"
            applicationId "com.example.charm"
        }
        strange {
            flavorDimension "bar"
            applicationId "com.example.strange"
        }
        // This is the idea of what I want, but it doesn't work because there
        // must be only a single dimension specified here.
        charmStrange {
            flavorDimension "foo", "bar"
            packageName "com.example.charminglystrange"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Since I wrote the question, the name of that variable has changed.  The fundamental nature of the question, however, has not.